# Wrong to have a function change the variable reference it was called from?

Tags: javascript, html

JavaScript has all amounts of crazy flexibility. I decided to take advantage of it and have a function change itself on the first call. Is this a bad thing to do? It works like this:

```
(function(){
   var nextAfter = function(){};
   Something.prototype.next = function(){
      //do pre-start actions.
      this.next = nextAfter;
   };
})();
```

This function is called inside of a main loop, so it gets called many times, but the instance is only ever "supposed" to be instantiated once.

Comment: "potential security threat"?

Comment: That function doesn't change itself. The `Something` prototype will still have a `next()` function, but when it is called it defines a `next()` directly on the object that is an instance of `Something`.

Comment: @nnnnnn I would have never caught that! I'm glad you said something about it. I guess at this point what I'm asking is different, such as: Having a function change the reference of the variable it was called from.

Comment: The code as shown would allow the "pre-start" actions to occur once and only once for every instance, which could be useful. I'm not sure what you mean by "change the reference of the variable". This code doesn't change any references, it modifies the instance it was called from. That's not "wrong" if it is what is required for your use case.

Comment: @nnnnnn How so? If `instance.next` is originally created as the prototype function, then **switched** over to `nextAfter` , I'm changing the what the variable(property) value of `instance.next` is. That's what I mean by changing a reference.

Comment: Interesting approach. Will it remain as understandable/maintainable for somebody else to follow later on? Why not use some explicit "pre-start complete" conditional check or property instead? Also, the effect is to redirect the actual instance method, not the prototype that defines it. It's like marking your town's road map "Elm St" but then forcing all first-time visitors driving the actual roads to use an unmarked detour down "Main St." instead as a way to ensure they pass your tourist traps :) The map itself doesn't change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a perfectly reasonable thing to do.

For example, It can be a useful way of implementing state changes in a state machine, but I'm sure that you could find many other uses.

You may also want to look into how to implement the same functionality with closures -- it may be cleaner depending on the use case.

**Edit;** example of a closure which doesn't change the prototype

```
Something = (function(){
    var next = function() { next = nextAfter; console.log("A"); }
    var nextAfter = function() { console.log("B"); }

    return {
        next: function(){ next(); }
    }
})();
```

The benefit of the closure is that you don't change the global prototype function for that object type, and you can now have multiple independent object where each closure object can keep their own state.

Comment: You said "same functionality with closures", I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean. My example is using a closure, but I don't think in the way you're referring too?

Comment: I added an example of a closure